# using C++ for developing freediameter extension

Tags: c++, free-diameter

So, I'd like to use C++ for developing freediameter extension,
The shared library is compiled and linked successfully, however when it is gonna be used by freediameter daemon, i receive this error:

```
01/16/17,00:04:59.215241  ERROR  Unable to resolve symbol 'fd_ext_init' for extension /home/usr/Downloads/freeDiameter-master/extensions/ocs_app/ocs_app.fdx: Undefined symbol "fd_ext_init"
01/16/17,00:04:59.215361  ERROR  ERROR: in '((fd_ext_load()))' :        Invalid argument
01/16/17,00:04:59.215377  ERROR  ERROR: in '(fd_core_parseconf(conffile))' :    Invalid argument
01/16/17,00:04:59.215387  FATAL! Initiating freeDiameter shutdown sequence (1)
```

I guess it has something with name mangling, but i cannot seems to find the solution. already tried to put the entry point into extern block but no luck:

```
extern "C" {
  static int ta_entry() {
     // C/C++ codes here ..
  }
}
```

also when i check "fd_ext_init" definition in the shared libary via nm, it'd be like:

```
0000000000008140 T _Z11fd_ext_initiiPc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good investigation!

Did you have `fd_ext_init` in your `extern "C"` block too?  All the APIs that freeDiameter wants to resolve by name at runtime need to be in the `extern "C"` block so that there names are not mangled.

Note that fd_ext_init is defined by the `EXTENSION_ENTRY` macro, so it's your invocation of that that needs to go in `extern "C"`.

(I wouldn't actually expect ta_entry to need to go in the `extern "C"` block - I think that this will not need to be resolved by name at runtime.)

I hope that helps!

Comment: Matt, thanks alot for reply. logically i found your answer correct :) I'll change the code and update you as soon as I get home